How can I troubleshoot an ipsec site-to-site vpn connection that only works one way?
I manage a site to site VPN connection from AWS to an on-premise Ubuntu server.
The connection works from AWS to on-prem, and I am able to reach all resources on-prem from AWS. However, I am unable to reach AWS resources from on-prem.
Looking at tcpdump on the on-prem gateway (192.168.100.10), whenever I do a ping from "on prem" to a resource on "aws" I see activity.
I'm stuck at figuring out where things break. I can't really dig any deeper on the AWS side than what Cloudwatch gives me, and the AWS logs are not very granular. I've gone over the AWS configurations multiple times, but can't really spot anything.
How can I continue troubleshooting traffic which seemingly does not reach AWS from on-prem?

A ping from 10.1.11.171 to 192.168.100.33 works :
root@ip-10-1-11-171:~#ping 192.168.100.33
PING 192.168.100.33 (192.168.100.33) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.100.33: icmp_seq=1 ttl=63 time=42.7 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.100.33: icmp_seq=2 ttl=63 time=41.5 ms

However, a ping from 192.168.100.10 to 10.1.11.171 does not work :
root@ip-192-168-100-10:/etc# ping 10.1.11.171
PING 10.1.11.171 (10.1.11.171) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 169.254.68.178 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 169.254.68.178 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable

The routing table on 192.168.100.10 :
root@ip-192-168-100-10:/etc# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         57.128.36.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 ens3
10.1.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     100    0        0 aws-ovh-1
10.1.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     200    0        0 aws-ovh-2
57.128.36.1     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    100    0        0 ens3
169.254.68.176  0.0.0.0         255.255.255.252 U     0      0        0 aws-ovh-1
169.254.91.20   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.252 U     0      0        0 aws-ovh-2
192.168.100.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 ens4
213.186.33.99   57.128.36.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   100    0        0 ens3

Validate routing to 10.1.11.171
root@ip-192-168-100-10:/etc# ip route get 10.1.11.171
10.1.11.171 dev aws-ovh-1 src 169.254.68.178 uid 0 
    cache 

On 192.168.100.10, inspecting traffic on the aws-ovh-1 interface when I ping 10.1.11.171 at the same time :
root@ip-192-168-100-10:/tmp# tcpdump -v -n -i aws-ovh-1
    13:45:23.721449 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 57469, offset 0, flags [DF], proto ICMP (1), length 84)
        169.254.68.178 > 10.1.11.171: ICMP echo request, id 58, seq 2, length 64
    13:45:24.745438 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 57499, offset 0, flags [DF], proto ICMP (1), length 84)
        169.254.68.178 > 10.1.11.171: ICMP echo request, id 58, seq 3, length 64
    13:45:25.769408 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 57637, offset 0, flags [DF], proto ICMP (1), length 84)
        169.254.68.178 > 10.1.11.171: ICMP echo request, id 58, seq 4, length 64
    13:45:26.793488 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 57782, offset 0, flags [DF], proto ICMP (1), length 84)

The relevant part of /etc/ipsec.conf on 192.168.100.10 :
conn aws-ovh-1
        type=tunnel
        auto=add
        keyexchange=ikev2
        authby=psk
        left=57.128.39.237 
        leftsubnet=192.168.100.0/24
        right=13.49.121.32
        rightsubnet=10.1.0.0/16  
        aggressive=no
        ikelifetime=28800s
        lifetime=3600s
        margintime=270s
        rekey=yes
        rekeyfuzz=100%
        fragmentation=yes
        replay_window=1024
        dpddelay=30s
        dpdtimeout=120s
        dpdaction=restart
        ike=aes128-sha1-modp1024
        esp=aes128-sha1-modp1024
        keyingtries=%forever

        ## Please note the following line assumes you only have two tunnels in your Strongswan configuration file. 
        ## This "mark" value must be unique and may need to be changed based on other entries in your configuration file.
        mark=100
        leftupdown="/etc/ipsec.d/aws-updown.sh -ln aws-ovh-1 -ll 169.254.68.178/30 -lr 169.254.68.177/30 -m 100 -r 10.1.0.0/16"

conn aws-ovh-2
        type=tunnel
        auto=add
        keyexchange=ikev2
        authby=psk
        left=57.128.39.237 
        leftsubnet=192.168.100.0/24
        right=13.51.87.152
        rightsubnet=10.1.0.0/16  
        aggressive=no
        ikelifetime=28800s
        lifetime=3600s
        margintime=270s
        rekey=yes
        rekeyfuzz=100%
        fragmentation=yes
        replay_window=1024
        dpddelay=30s
        dpdtimeout=120s
        dpdaction=restart
        ike=aes128-sha1-modp1024
        esp=aes128-sha1-modp1024
        keyingtries=%forever

        ## Please note the following line assumes you only have two tunnels in your Strongswan configuration file. 
        ## This "mark" value must be unique and may need to be changed based on other entries in your configuration file.
        mark=200
        leftupdown="/etc/ipsec.d/aws-updown.sh -ln aws-ovh-2 -ll 169.254.91.22/30 -lr 169.254.91.21/30 -m 200 -r 10.1.0.0/16"

IPTables output from 192.168.100.10 for nat table
root@ip-192-168-100-10:/etc# iptables -L -v -t nat
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
 2056  191K SNAT       all  --  any    ens4    anywhere             anywhere             to:192.168.100.10

IPTables output from 192.168.100.10 for mangle table
root@ip-192-168-100-10:/etc# iptables -L -v -t mangle
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 MARK       esp  --  any    any     ec2-13-51-87-152.eu-north-1.compute.amazonaws.com  ip-192-168-100-10             MARK set 0xc8
    0     0 MARK       esp  --  any    any     ec2-13-49-121-32.eu-north-1.compute.amazonaws.com  ip-192-168-100-10             MARK set 0x64

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 TCPMSS     tcp  --  any    aws-ovh-2  anywhere             anywhere             tcp flags:SYN,RST/SYN TCPMSS clamp to PMTU
   64  3840 TCPMSS     tcp  --  any    aws-ovh-1  anywhere             anywhere             tcp flags:SYN,RST/SYN TCPMSS clamp to PMTU

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination  

   

Route table for the AWS private subnet :


Have you checked security groups? They're a leading suspect when things only work in one direction. NACLs are stateless so worth checking too, easy to allow one direction but not the other. Routing also worth checking.

Thanks @Tim for your suggestions. Security groups allow traffic from all sources on the port I have tested with. There is only the default rule in NACL (allow all incoming and outgoing), and a static route has been configured for local AWS resources with route propagation enabled (which should take care of routing traffic to 10.1.11.171).

That was worth checking. Given you're getting replies to your pings from on-prem to AWS I have to guess the problem is on the on-prem side with connection setup, but my expertise is on the AWS side of things. Are you using AWS VPN or setting up a software VPN? I'm puzzled why your AWS side resources have two CIDR ranges, I'm guessing you're using a software VPN otherwise you wouldn't need a gateway. I suggest if you're not already it's worth trying an AWS VPN, either with a VPG or from a TGW.

@tim it seems that everything is good on the AWS side. I've debugged this to the point where I can see response packets on the onprem gateway (192.168.100.10), and upon inspection i can see that source ip is 10.1.11.171 and destination is 192.168.100.33. However, the packets do not arrive at 192.168.100.33 (tcpdump shows original outgoing packet, but not response packets). So, trying to figure out if there's anything about the routing that goes wrong. However, on 192.168.100.10 i tcpdump on the 192.168.100.0/24 interface, so I believe routing is OK.

Unfortunately I don't have the networking knowledge to help further. I typically work with a networking specialist who does the on-premises side of the VPN connections. Hopefully someone here can help, otherwise you could try AWS Support.
